# Cannot Read Property of Undefined Passing LocalStorage Value to View Component Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to pass the value that I'm recieving from localstoage to my view component. For some reason I'm getting undefined, however in the console I am getting data back from the local storage.

What am I doing wrong?

**ModifyView.Component.TS**

```
    export class ModifyViewComponent {

  @Input() ActionMenuLines: ActionMenuLine[];
  @Input() currentAction: Action;
  @Input() currentUser: User;
    close: any;
    viewData: any;
    viewTag: number;
    action: any;
    dataSource: ViewDataSource;
    fetchedData: any;
    primaryTableValue: any;
    defaultSortCol = '1';



  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private actionService: ActionService) {}

  // tslint:disable-next-line: use-life-cycle-interface
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initData();
  }

  initData() {
    const action = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('DbrAction'));
    console.log(action);
  }
}
```

ModifyView.Component.HTML

```
    <div>
    <mat-card class="view-settings-descrpition-card">
      <mat-card-header>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>{{action.ActionName}}</p>
      </mat-card-content>
      </mat-card>
</div>
```

Comment: what is `console.log(action);` loging ?

Comment: it's logging the action object which is stored in local storage, that part is working i just can't get it to the html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `const` and try by using `this.action = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('DbrAction'));`

Comment: @kjamp it works because through  `action` variable you will like to bind the html with data.  Also`const` scope is within that function only

Answer (score 2):

Declare a global class variable and update it like this:

```
export class ModifyViewComponent {

  dbrAction: any;
  // ... other parts of code

  // tslint:disable-next-line: use-life-cycle-interface
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initData();
  }

  initData() {
    this.dbrAction= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('DbrAction'));
    console.log(this.dbrAction);
  }
}
```

In HTML use this variable:

```
<div>
    <mat-card class="view-settings-descrpition-card">
      <mat-card-header>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>
        <p> {{ dbrAction.ActionName }}</p>
      </mat-card-content>
      </mat-card>
</div>
```

Hope it will solve your problem...